# Phonegap Android Inline SVG

Tags: android, cordova, svg, svg-filters

I am using Phonegap to develop an Android application that is only going to be used on the Nexus 7.

In the index.html I have an inline svg that draws some nice circles and does a pulse effect.

It works wonderfully in Chrome on the computer AND in Chrome on the Nexus 7.
However, when I compile the .apk or have Eclipse push a debug version of the application to the device, the svg does not show up.

The background image of the application and all other menu elements show as well, just the items in the svg area in the middle do not appear.

Here is the svg code segment:

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 1205">

<radialGradient id = "blipPulse" cx = "50%" cy = "50%" r = "50%">

    <stop stop-color = "#3ddeed" offset = "0%" stop-opacity = "0.2">
        <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" begin="0s" dur="3s" values="1;0;1" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </stop>
    <stop stop-color = "#3ddeed" offset = "0%" stop-opacity = "1">
        <animate attributeName="offset" begin="0s" dur="3s" values="0;1;1;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="stop-opacity" begin="0s" dur="3s" values="0;1;0;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </stop>

    <stop stop-color = "#3ddeed" offset = "2" stop-opacity = "0">
</radialGradient>
<defs>
    <g id="blip">
    <circle cx = "0" cy = "0" r = "20" fill = "url(#blipPulse)" stroke = "#3ddeed" stroke-width = "2" opacity="0.3"/>
    <circle cx = "0" cy = "0" r = "7" fill = "#3ddeed" stroke = "none" stroke-width = "0"/>
    </g>
    <path id="hex" d="m 0 -60 L 52 -30 L 52 30 L 0 60 L -52 30 L -52 -30 L 0 -60" fill="rgba(255,255,255,0.15)" />
</defs>

<radialGradient id = "g1" cx = "50%" cy = "50%" r = "50%">
    <stop stop-color = "#3ddeed" offset = "0%"  stop-opacity = "0"/>
    <stop stop-color = "#3ddeed" offset = "60%" stop-opacity = "0"/>
    <stop stop-color = "#3ddeed" offset = "86%" stop-opacity = "0.1"/>
    <stop stop-color = "#3ddeed" offset = "100%" stop-opacity = "0.25"/>
</radialGradient>
<filter id = "fearth" x = "0%" y = "0%" width = "100%" height = "100%">
    <feImage xlink:href = "assets/earth.png"/>
</filter>
<filter id = "fasteroid1" x = "0%" y = "0%" width = "100%" height = "100%">
    <feImage xlink:href = "assets/Asteroids/ice1.png"/>
</filter>
<filter id = "fasteroid2" x = "0%" y = "0%" width = "100%" height = "100%">
    <feImage xlink:href = "assets/Asteroids/ice2.png"/>
</filter>
<filter id = "fasteroid3" x = "0%" y = "0%" width = "100%" height = "100%">
    <feImage xlink:href = "assets/Asteroids/iron1.png"/>
</filter>
<filter id = "fasteroid4" x = "0%" y = "0%" width = "100%" height = "100%">
    <feImage xlink:href = "assets/Asteroids/iron2.png"/>
</filter>
<filter id = "ffleetcolor" x = "0%" y = "0%" width = "100%" height = "100%">
    <feImage xlink:href = "assets/Asteroids/fleeticoncolor.png"/>
</filter>
<filter id = "ffleetgray" x = "0%" y = "0%" width = "100%" height = "100%">
    <feImage xlink:href = "assets/Asteroids/fleeticongray.png"/>
</filter>
<filter id = "fdeployarrow" x = "0%" y = "0%" width = "100%" height = "100%">
    <feImage xlink:href = "assets/Asteroids/deployarrow.png"/>
</filter>

<g id="mapcenter" transform="translate(400,600)">
<g id="map" transform="scale(1) translate(0,0)">
<circle cx="-800" cy="0" r="800" id="orbit" />
<circle id="rangering" cx="0" cy="0" r="400" fill="url(#g1)" transform="scale(0)" />
<g id="blips">
    <use id="loc0" x = "100" y = "150" xlink:href = "#blip" opacity="0" />
    <use id="loc1" x = "-180" y = "110" xlink:href = "#blip" opacity="0" />
    <use id="loc2" x = "230" y = "-70" xlink:href = "#blip" opacity="0" />
</g>
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="17" fill="blue" filter="url(#fearth)" id="earth" />
<g id="asteroidfield" transform="translate(100,150) scale(0.05)">
    <circle cx="48" cy="-146" r="25" fill="grey" filter="url(#fasteroid1)" id="asteroid1" />
    <circle cx="-120" cy="-230" r="25" fill="grey" filter="url(#fasteroid2)" id="asteroid2" />
    <circle cx="190" cy="90" r="25" fill="grey" filter="url(#fasteroid3)" id="asteroid3" />
    <circle cx="-277" cy="270" r="25" fill="grey" filter="url(#fasteroid4)" id="asteroid4" />
</g>
<g id="asteroidinfo">
    <rect x="-30" y="-105" width="60" height="45" fill="red" filter="url(#fdeployarrow)" id="deployarrow" />
    <circle cx="0" cy="-125" r="45" fill="blue" filter="url(#ffleetcolor)" id="fleetcolor" />
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="45" fill="blue" filter="url(#ffleetgray)" id="fleetgray" />
    <g id="h2ohex" transform="translate(108,-125)">
        <use id="h2ohex" xlink:href = "#hex" opacity="1" />
        <text x = "0" y = "0" class="hexValue">60</text>
        <text x = "0" y = "30"  class="hexLabel">H<tspan baseline-shift = "sub" font-size="0.7em">2</tspan>O</text>
    </g>
    <g id="fehex" transform="translate(180,0)">
        <use xlink:href = "#hex" opacity="1" />
        <text x = "0" y = "0" class="hexValue">50</text>
        <text x = "0" y = "30"  class="hexLabel">Fe</text>
    </g>
    <g id="pthex" transform="translate(108,125)">
        <use xlink:href = "#hex" opacity="1" />
        <text x = "0" y = "0" class="hexValue">10</text>
        <text x = "0" y = "30"  class="hexLabel">Pt</text>
    </g>
</g>

</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: After looking further into the issue, I can get it to draw just a single circle in the SVG. So this is leading me to believe that there is an error in the SVG code itself and not an issue with rendering SVG's in general. I'll get back once I've line by line re-added all the SVG code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embedded webview of the Nexus 7 is still the Android 4x browsing engine - which doesn't support filters.